# XPath to select nodes with certain name or attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to remove `footer` section from html source.

Consider the following cases,

```
<div id="footer">Blabla</div>
```

or

```
<div class="footer">Blabla</div>
```

or

```
<footer>Blablabla</footer>
```

How can I match the above cases using XPath?

Comment: You're aware that _no_ attribute contains `foo` in the sample you provide? (XPath works on XML trees; XML is case-sensitive).

Comment: Did you make an attempt to solve what you wanted? If yes, then please feel free to share the code, so you get the help you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would come up with something like this:

```
//*[contains(lower-case(@*),'footer')] | //footer
```

Comment: In my php code, i just removed the `lower-case` function, it works fine!

In my script, DOMDocument was loaded from HTML, where element and attribute names are case-insensitive, the DOM parser converts them all to lower-case.